# p:pickList not fetching data after pressing p:commandButton

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a users list page which holds the users in a `p:dataTable` and in each row I have an *update* button that shows a `p:dialog` popup.
The page and the dialog is managed in view scope (implemented in Spring).

When I press the `editUserButton` in the main page the popup appears with all data and then I type an invalid string into the fields *email* and *username*. The validation message appears, but the picklist is not populated with any value.

What could be the problem?

This is the main page (users list) snippet code:

```
<ui:composition>
<f:view id="bodyView">
    <div id="content_body">
        <ui:include src="editUserDialog.xhtml"/>
        <h:form id="usersListForm">
        <table width="85%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p:dataTable id="usersList" var="user" 
                             value="#{usersController.usersList}"
                             selectionMode="single"
                             rowKey="#{user.userId}">
                        <p:columnGroup type="header">
                            <p:row>
                                ...
                                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Users"/>
                                ...
                            </p:row>
                        </p:columnGroup>
                            ...
                        <p:column id="users" >
                            <p:commandLink id="editUserButton" oncomplete="addEditUserConfirmation.show()" actionListener="#{addEditUserController.selectionListener}"
                                    update=":addEditCustomerDialogForm:dialogContent">
                                    <f:attribute value="#{user}" name="selectedUser" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</f:view>
```

This is the p:dialog code:

```
<ui:composition>
<h:form id="addEditUserDialogForm">
        <p:dialog id="addEditUserDialog" severity="alert" widgetVar="addEditUserConfirmation" draggable="true" modal="true"
              resizable="false" >
        <p:outputPanel id="dialogContent">
        <div>
            <table cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:inputText value="#{addEditUserController.addEditCustomerBean.userName}"
                                maxlength="250" size="50" label="user name" id="userName">
                            <f:validator validatorId="UsernameValidator"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="userName"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:inputText value="#{addEditUserController.addEditCustomerBean.email}"
                                maxlength="50" size="50" label="E-mail" id="email">
                            <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="email"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:pickList id="customersList" iconOnly="true"
                                    value="#{addEditUserController.customersList}" var="customer"
                                    itemValue="#{customer.value}" itemLabel="#{customer.label}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div align="right">
            <p:commandButton value="#{isNewUser ? 'add' : 'update'}" id="updateUserButton"
                                         actionListener="#{addEditUserController.persistUser}"
                                         update="dialogContent"
                                         styleClass="fiftyone-default-button"
                                oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>
        </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        if(!(args.validationFailed &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed == true)) {
            addEditUserConfirmation.hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the backing bean code:

```
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel; 
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;

public class AddEditUserController {
   private AddEditCustomerBean addEditCustomerBean;
   private DualListModel<LabelValueBean> customersList;

   // ... constructor getters and setters

   public void selectionListener(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        selectedUser = event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedUser");
        // some code
        AddEditCustomerBean = new AddEditCustomerBean();
        // some code
        customersList = getSomeCustomersDualListModel()
    }

    public void persistUser() throws Exception {
       // save user to DB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do would be to make sure that the method `selectionListener` is being called (either put a break-point on it or print something and check in the console later).

If it is, you must check if the variable `customersList` is being updated correctly, if it's not, you probably have a problem with bean scoping.

In your sample code it isn't clear how you are setting the scope for the backing bean, so I assume you're doing it on Spring's XML config file.

Make sure you really have the backing bean in the view scope, by inspecting the contents of the view map: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap()`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I also encountered this issue recently, and now being helpless. Let's see the p:pickList:

```
                <td>
                    <p:pickList id="customersList" iconOnly="true"
                                value="#{addEditUserController.customersList}" var="customer"
                                itemValue="#{customer.value}" itemLabel="#{customer.label}"/>
                </td>
```

We know the [var="customer"] is an iterator, but when validation error happens, this var is assigned to String type, it's odd. When you close this popup then re-populate it again, you will get an error, messages like this: no property label(value) on type of String...  the customer var now is a String, so it has no value nor label property.

For now, I use a tricky way, it won't work out always, it depends on your code:
 Assume that the value and label are unique, set customersList type of List String, customersList binds the label, find the value of the label when submit at the backend; Why this way can avoid re-populate exception, that's because the iterator is always type of String, no matter validation error occurs or not.

Hope this can help the need.